# Splitting the string using a symbol in python

Tags: python, string, list, split, element

I have the following string:

```
my_string = '1) ServerName sn = ProtobufUtil.toServerName(request.getServer());\\n2) String msg = "Region server " + sn +\\n3)  " reported a fatal error:\\\\n" + errorText;\\n4) LOG.error(msg);'
```

I need to convert that string into a list split by symbol `\\n`. So, the list will be like this:

```
my_list = ['1) ServerName sn = ProtobufUtil.toServerName(request.getServer());',
           '2) String msg = "Region server " + sn +',
           '3)  " reported a fatal error:\\\\n" + errorText;',
           '4) LOG.error(msg);'
          ]
```

I used the symbol `\\n` as the splitter in my code:

```
my_list = my_string.split("\\n")
```

However, the output for the third element in the list is not as I expected.
Output:

```
my_list = ['1) ServerName sn = ProtobufUtil.toServerName(request.getServer());',
           '2) String msg = "Region server " + sn +',
           '3)  " reported a fatal error:\\',
           '" + errorText;',
           '4) LOG.error(msg);']
```

How should the splitter be defined in the code?

Comment: Please explain why the output is not what you expected. It looks quite expected to me. Try to form some idea as to how to do this yourself.

Comment: The third element in the list should be one element `'3)  " reported a fatal error:\\\\n" + errorText;',`, but it is split into two elements.

Comment: Yes, but why? That output is totally expected...

Comment: Because in the third element, symbol `\\n` after `fatal error:` is a part of the code in line 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got no option but the regex option. You can do this with `re.split`, and a negative lookbehind.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r'(?<!\\)\\n', my_string)
```

```
[
    '1) ServerName sn = ProtobufUtil.toServerName(request.getServer())',
    '2) String msg = "Region server " + sn ',
    '3)  " reported a fatal error:\\\\n" + errorText',
    '4) LOG.error(msg);'
]
```

The lookbehind specifies that the split must occur only when `\\n` isn't preceded by more backslashes.

Comment: Technically you should be looking for any odd number times two number of backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this pattern , which is Positive Lookahead :

```
pattern r'\\n(?=\d)'
```

code:

```
my_string = '1) ServerName sn = ProtobufUtil.toServerName(request.getServer());\\n2) String msg = "Region server " + sn +\\n3)  " reported a fatal error:\\\\n" + errorText;\\n4) LOG.error(msg);'

import re

for i in re.split(r'\\n(?=\d)',my_string):
    print(i)
```

output:

```
1) ServerName sn = ProtobufUtil.toServerName(request.getServer());
2) String msg = "Region server " + sn +
3)  " reported a fatal error:\\n" + errorText;
4) LOG.error(msg);
```